# How to look at the transaction logs or events in ganache-cli

Tags: ganache

When I make a transaction in my dapp that's connected to ganache, there is a transaction hash shown in the ganache logs but not the events that that transaction emitted. I want to see the events that the transaction emitted. Is there a way to see all the events that that transaction emits if I only have the transaction hash? This question is for ganache-cli and not ganache ui.

Comment: I see an answer it was for gui.but I think it can be helpfull, you can search about it. https://tonyyan.wordpress.com/2021/02/25/where-are-my-contracts-and-events-on-ganache/